# Silverlight DescriptionViewer prevent Tooltip to disappear on click

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, tooltip, silverlight-toolkit

The Silverlight 4 `DescriptionViewer` Control displays a `Description` in a Tooltip:

The syntax is pretty easy: Add Namespace `xmlns:dataInput="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data.Input"` and the following XAML to your UserControl:

```
<dataInput:DescriptionViewer Description="Some hints on user input etc." />
```

Unfortunately, some users click on the displayed Icon (since it even hovers by default) which instantly closes the Tooltip (the actual and only information). Even worse, when you click very quickly after hovering, the Tooltip even won't appear at all, so the user might think the Icon has no function at all.

I'd like to prevent closing the Tooltip on Click (just close on "mouse out"), even better clicking should force the Tooltip to show immediately (skipping the usual timeout before shown).

It seems to be harder then I though, since there is no `OnClick` event and also `MouseLeftButtonDown` seems to not fire at all. I also tried to override the `DescriptionViewer` Control but also no luck finding the appropriate methods to override.

Can you help? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this actually has nothing to do with the DescriptionViewer, it is the behavior of the ToolTip. The ToolTip will disappear once you do a mouse click. In this case you might want to write you own ToolTip.

I think normally when you click on the DescriptionViewer icon, there should be a new window open which is like a more detailed help page. So the user wouldn't get confused.

**Update:**

You can achieve this by defining an attached property. Basically, you attach this property to the Button inside your DescriptionViewer. When the Button's Click event is fired, you find the Tooltip underneath the Button and set its IsOpen to ture. Then you also need to handle the MouseLeave event to hide the Tooltip once your mouse's away.

This is how the attached property is defined.

public static class ButtonAttachedProperties
{
    public static bool GetOpenToolTip(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(OpenToolTipProperty);
    }

```
public static void SetOpenToolTip(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
{
    obj.SetValue(OpenToolTipProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty OpenToolTipProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("OpenToolTip", typeof(bool), typeof(ButtonAttachedProperties), new PropertyMetadata(false, Callback));


private static void Callback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = d as Button;

    if (button == null || !(bool)e.NewValue) return;

    button.Click += (s, e1) =>
    {
        var tooltip = button.FindName("MyToolTip") as ToolTip;

        if (tooltip != null)
        {
            tooltip.PlacementTarget = button;
            tooltip.IsOpen = true;      
        }
    };

    button.MouseLeave += (s, e2) =>
    {
        var tooltip = button.FindName("MyToolTip") as ToolTip;

        if (tooltip != null)
            tooltip.IsOpen = false;
    };
}
```

}

Then in the DescriptionViewer's style, you attach the property to the Button. Also you need to name the Tooltip in order to be able to find it using FindName in the attach property class.

```
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}">
                            <Button x:Name="DescriptionContent" local:ButtonAttachedProperties.OpenToolTip="True" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="1" Background="#00000000" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsTabStop="False" Padding="1" Template="{TemplateBinding GlyphTemplate}" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                    <ToolTip x:Name="MyToolTip" Content="{TemplateBinding Description}" PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{TemplateBinding ToolTipStyle}"/>
                                </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            </Button>
                        </Border>
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: "there should be a new window open which is like a more detailed help page" - yeah why not, but still I can't handle the mouse click to do that. Looks like I should write my own DescriptionViewer.

Comment: if you just want the mouse click then that's easy. you can edit the default style of the descrption viewer and find a button called DescriptionContent inside the template and handle its Click event from there.

Comment: Ok I understand the concept behind this, but I actually dont find it so easy doing that in a elegant, reusable manner :)

Comment: yes if you want it to be generic then it's a little bit more work. Please see my updated answer. :)

Comment: Excellent, that worked! But don't you think it would be good to unsubscribe from the `Click` and `MouseLeave` events? What do you think about subscribing to "button.Unloaded", changing the mouse events from lambda to regular handlers and unsubscribe from all three events (Unloaded/Click/MouseLeave) when "button.Unloaded" occurs? Good idea? Or is there a better place to do this or is this even not necessary?

Comment: Hi as the CallBack method will only be called once, when you set the attached property to TRUE the two events will only be subscribed once. So I guess this is not necessary. ;)