# How can I place one control in a callout that orginates from another control in XAML?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, user-interface, positioning

Here is a setup: I have a textbox with a numberic value. According to the requirements every time anybody changes that value an accompanying comment needs to be provided. So visually there must be another textbox for the comment that should be displayed right next to the first one. Ideally the comment textbox needs to be placed in a callout that originates from the value textbox and displayed on the right from it overlaying anything what's underneath of it just like on this picture: [image]

I know how to do easily it in CSS and HTML.
I have to do the same in Silverlight now.
Unfortunately I am not very strong in it, so what I am specifically asking about is how having 2 textboxes make one of them appear next to another (on the right overlaying whatever controls are underneath it) with as less XAML and code as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ToolTip`, and set the Placement such that it appears to the right. in XAML, you can template your `ToolTip` to look however you want, even if that means mimicking the `TextBox` appearance.

This is the purpose of the `ToolTip`, and I feel strongly that you should always use the right tool for the right job. :)

I hope this helps. Let us know if you need code samples.

EDIT: Added the following code samples:

```
    <TextBox ToolTipService.Placement="Right">
        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding CalloutText, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
    </TextBox>
```

Comment: How can I control its position?

Comment: You can set the position with the `ToolTipService.Placement` `AttachedProperty`. You can also use `ToolTipService.VerticalOffset` and `ToolTipService.HorizontalOffset` to adjust the positioning. If you need more control, consider using `ToolTipService.PlacementRectangle`.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I make a tooltip stay? I disappears once the owner control looses the focus.

Comment: Use `ToolTipService.ShowDuration AttachedProperty` to adjust the length of time it remains active.

Comment: Well I need it to stay as long as either the value texbox or the comment texbox holds the focus. So it is not an absolute time range that I know beforehand.

Comment: Set it to `Duration.Forever`

Comment: How do I get rid of it when I no longer need it?

Comment: ShowDuration doesn't exist in silverlight

Comment: Your question only says `XAML`, I missed the part that specified `Silverlight`. This is a bit trickier in `Silverlight`, and you are going to have to write a custom `Control` (or at least some custom code). I think the following post might be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830219/silverlight-descriptionviewer-prevent-tooltip-to-disappear-on-click

Comment: Everything is ass-backwards in Silverlight, I am glad you noticed, check out my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I ended up writing my own behaviour

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class CommentBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
    {
        private readonly TimeSpan howLongWeWaitBeforePopupCloses = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200);

        private DispatcherTimer popupClosingTimer;
        public static DependencyProperty PopupProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Popup", typeof(Popup), typeof(CommentBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public Popup Popup
        {
            get { return (Popup)this.GetValue(PopupProperty); }
            set { this.SetValue(PopupProperty, value); }
        }

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            this.popupClosingTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            this.popupClosingTimer.Stop();
            this.popupClosingTimer.Interval = howLongWeWaitBeforePopupCloses;
            this.popupClosingTimer.Tick += this.ClosePopup;
            this.AssociatedObject.GotFocus += this.GotFocus;
            this.AssociatedObject.LostFocus += this.LostFocus;
            this.Popup.Child.GotFocus += PopupChild_GotFocus;
            this.Popup.Child.LostFocus += PopupChild_LostFocus;
        }

        private void PopupChild_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.popupClosingTimer.Start();
        }

        private void PopupChild_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.popupClosingTimer.Stop();
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            this.AssociatedObject.GotFocus -= this.GotFocus;
            this.AssociatedObject.LostFocus -= this.LostFocus;
            this.Popup.GotFocus -= PopupChild_GotFocus;
            this.popupClosingTimer.Tick -= this.ClosePopup;
            this.popupClosingTimer = null;
        }

        private void ClosePopup(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Popup.IsOpen = false;
            this.popupClosingTimer.Stop();
        }

        protected void GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.popupClosingTimer.Stop();
            this.Popup.IsOpen = true;
            var at = this.CalculatePopupPosition();
            this.Popup.HorizontalOffset = at.X;
            this.Popup.VerticalOffset = at.Y;
        }

        private Point CalculatePopupPosition()
        {
            var owner = this.AssociatedObject;
            var transformation = owner.TransformToVisual(Application.Current.RootVisual);
            var at = transformation.Transform(new Point(owner.ActualWidth, 0));
            return at;
        }

        protected void LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.popupClosingTimer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

And the following XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Background="Red">
        <TextBox Width="200" Text="0.01">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <local:CommentBehavior>
                    <local:CommentBehavior.Popup>
                        <Popup>
                            <TextBox Text="Comment" />
                        </Popup>
                    </local:CommentBehavior.Popup>
                </local:CommentBehavior>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```